# Showing images uploaded on php page

Tags: php

I Have a problem while uploading image to my php page .. i tried this code and its worked and the image uploaded but i can't show it on the page ..

please help ^^

```
if ($_FILES["img"]["name"]) {

$name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['img']['error'];

    if (!empty($name)) {
        $location = '/var/www/html/1.jpg'; 

        if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Image Uploaded';
            echo nl2br("\n");
            echo nl2br("\n");

            echo <<<HEREDOC

            <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
            <img src="{$location}" alt = "Ur Image" width="400" height="400"/>
            </div>
HEREDOC;

        }

    }
    else {
        echo 'please choose a file';
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste this in a browser and see the image?  /var/www/html/1.jpg

Comment: shouldn't the path to the image be src='1.jpg' rather than src='/var/www/html/1.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that the issue is related to your $location variable. When you save the file, you save it to /var/www/html/1.jpg1.jpg since you do $location.$name, but when you try and display it, you only use the $location, which is /var/www/html/1.jpg.

Essentially, change:

```
<img src="{$location}" alt = "Ur Image" width="400" height="400"/>
```

to

```
<img src="{$location.$name}" alt = "Ur Image" width="400" height="400"/>
```

**EDIT**
And as meta pointed out, don't use /var/www/html/... in the image source. If /var/www/html is the root of the website where the PHP file lives, change yout $location variable to

```
$location = '/var/www/html/';
```

And change

```
<img src="{$location}" alt = "Ur Image" width="400" height="400"/>
```

to

```
<img src="{$name}" alt = "Ur Image" width="400" height="400"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use physical location `/var/www...` in `src`, use URL instead (which would depend on your http server configuration). But you can try something like `http://your.domain/1.jpg`
or localhost/i.jpg or you could even try relative path `src="/1.jpg"` or `src="html/1.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the image is uploading where you think it is suppoed to go

```
if(isset($_POST['addImage'])){

   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

   $target_dir = "$myfolder/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);                    
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_file);

} else {
   die('<br>An error occurred importing the file: '.$_FILES['userfile']['error']);
}
```

then show image with src='$target_file'